# Does there exist a finite false proposition $P$ such that assuming $P$ we can derive any given false proposition?

Tags: logic, philosophy

I'm unsure if this is an appropriate question to ask, in some sense it seems closer to philosophy, but it's something I've wondered for a while.
If it is not an appropriate question say so and I'll take it down.

> 1. Does there exist a false proposition $P$ which can be written in a
>    finite number of characters such that assuming $P$ we can derive any
>    given false proposition?
> 2. Does there exist a false proposition $P$ which can be written in a
>    finite number of characters such that assuming $P$ we can derive any
>    given proposition?

(note this may include contradictions such as interchangeably being able to use $1<2$ and $1>2$).

My thoughts were initially that for $1.$, it ought to be the same as the answer to the question

"Does there exist a true proposition $P$ which can be written in a finite number of characters such that assuming $P$ we can derive any given true proposition?" but then here to determine that such a $P$ is true we must derive it from axioms, and so this question is equivalent to asking whether or not all true statements are provable, which I think I'm right in saying that the answer to this is 'no'.

However, I think the answer to the original question $(1.)$ needn't be 'no' as we have the usual axioms to work with in addition to a new set of results to use derived from $P$ together with usual axioms, and so I simply don't know.

Thanks and feel free to let me know if the question should be taken down.

Comment: I am not sure if i understood what exactly your question is, but do you mean the "classic" Ex-falso-quodlibet?

Comment: If you start with a contradiction (for instance, $x\ne x $), you can derive anything.

Comment: @Diamir yes, sorry I didn't know this was a thing. I will read the wikipedia page now. Thank you. If you or anyone wants to post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: *All sets are empty* looks for a good starting point for proving everything, disregarding its actual truth value.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No, that's not contradictory enough - it has a model $(\{\emptyset\}, \in)$, and so is consistent. Now, it *in conjunction with other axioms* will be inconsistent, but on its own ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a subtlety in "ex falso quodlibet" which is often overlooked: it *not true* that from a false statement, we can deduce anything, but rather that from a *known false statement* (that is, a contradiction) we can deduce anything.

To illustrate the difference, take a theory like Peano arithmetic. PA is (let's say for the sake of argument) consistent, but by Godel's second incompleteness theorem this means that PA+"PA is inconsistent" is consistent. "PA is inconsistent" is obviously false, so why can't we prove everything from PA+"PA is inconsistent"? Well, the reason is that - although "PA is inconsistent" is false - PA doesn't *know* that "PA is inconsistent" is false (that is, PA can't prove its own consistency), so EFQ doesn't apply here.

In particular, this means that the theory consisting *only* of the sentence "PA is inconsistent," and no other axioms, is consistent, i.e. doesn't prove everything.

What you're looking for is a *logical contradiction* - a sentence which isn't true in *any* theory. Equivalently, a sentence $p$ such that $p$ alone proves every sentence. These sentences exist - e.g. "$\exists x(x\not=x)$" is such a sentence. Moreover, these sentences are false (of course), so any sentence proving all false sentences proves these, and hence proves all sentences - so your (1) and (2) are in fact equivalent.